# Upload Description with inline CSS in Rally .NET SDK

Tags: rally

I have desktop utility app to upload updates and create new user stories to Rally. I am using a WPF Richtextbox and am using the XAML to HTML conversion demo found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa972129%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

When i try to upload the user story that has richtext formatting it fails with the following error in the CreateResult object:

```
"Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: expected '}'
but saw 'f' [ chars read = >>>{\"hierarchicalrequirement\":{\"Name\":\"Test
Story\",\"Description\":\"<HTML><BODY><P><SPAN STYLE=\"f<<< ]"
```

This is the entire string:

```
"<HTML><BODY><P><SPAN STYLE=\"font-weight:bold;\">This is a test</SPAN> of a new story.</P></BODY></HTML>"
```

When i read in another user story that has bold text it uses the "strong" HTML tag. The converter uses only inline CSS. Does the Rally API support inline CSS and i just need to reformat the string since it fails at the first quotation mark (")?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rally supports much in the way of markup in the Description field - I think this is related to the version of the .NET REST DLL that you are using, rather than a Rally server-side issue. I tested creating a story via the most current [.NET REST Toolkit](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/rest-api-net) using your test string, was able to correctly create the Story, including the formatting.

What version of the .NET REST Toolkit DLL are you using? Some versions had an issue serializing the data into JSON when some strings contained HTML markup.

The most current version: [REST .NET 1.0.15 DLL](http://people.rallydev.com/connector/RallyRestApiDotNet/Rally.RestApi-1.0.15.zip) that I used in my testing, successfully creates a User Story with the above Test String that includes the markup of interest - no parsing errors were seen.

Comment: That seemed to do it. I was using the 1.0.7 version so it was obviously out of date. Once I updated my Create function to contain the Workspace string everything worked. Thank you.